# How to display the grid over tiles in a geo map bokeh plot

Tags: python, bokeh

Grid is displayed under the tiles. Is there a way to display it over (z-index control) ?

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.tile_providers import CARTODBPOSITRON, get_provider
from bokeh.models import MercatorAxis, Grid

tile_provider = get_provider(CARTODBPOSITRON)

# range bounds supplied in web mercator coordinates
p = figure(x_range=(-2000000, 6000000), y_range=(-1000000, 7000000),
           x_axis_type="mercator", y_axis_type="mercator")

p.add_layout(MercatorAxis(), 'above')
p.add_layout(MercatorAxis(), 'right')

# possible controls but not visible
p.grid.grid_line_dash = [6, 4]
p.grid.grid_line_alpha = 1
p.grid.grid_line_color = 'gray'

p.add_tile(tile_provider)

show(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `level` value as a keyword argument.

This is the line to change:
`p.add_tile(tile_provider, level='image')`
This is the result:
[image]

**firts try**

I first modified the `alpha` value (also a keyword argument).
This is the line I changed:
`p.add_tile(tile_provider, alpha=0.7)`

And this is the output:[image]

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, it seems to be the default behavior in Bokeh 2.3. You can try using a development version or just wait till it's released.

Comment: I haven't been able to run your answer. No effect.

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right. My initial code did absolutely nothing in your case, and I didn't realize that I was trying to run it on Bokeh 2.3 dev preview.